# InternetQueryOption crashes on Windows XP

Tags: c++, winapi, wininet

The following code is more or less just copied from MSDN documentation. On Windows Vista and Windows 7 it works fine, but in crashes on XP with an access violation int the call to `InternetQueryOption`.
Anyone got an idea what the problem could be?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen("x", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
  //
  // 1. Set
  //
  {
    INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST    List;
    INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION         Option[2];
    unsigned long                    nSize = sizeof(INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST);

    Option[0].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_URL;
    Option[0].Value.pszValue = "http://myserver/get_proxy_info.dll";
    Option[1].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
    Option[1].Value.dwValue = PROXY_TYPE_AUTO_PROXY_URL;

    List.dwSize = sizeof(INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST);
    List.pszConnection = NULL;
    List.dwOptionCount = 2;
    List.dwOptionError = 0;
    List.pOptions = Option;

    if(!InternetSetOption(hInternet, INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, &List, nSize))
       printf("InternetQueryOption failed! (%d)\n", GetLastError());
  }
  //
  // 2. Query
  //
  {
    INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST    List;
    INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION         Option[5];
    unsigned long                    nSize = sizeof(INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST);

    Option[0].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_URL;
    Option[1].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTODISCOVERY_FLAGS;
    Option[2].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
    Option[3].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS;
    Option[4].dwOption = INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;

    List.dwSize = sizeof(INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST);
    List.pszConnection = NULL;
    List.dwOptionCount = 5;
    List.dwOptionError = 0;
    List.pOptions = Option;

    printf("InternetQueryOption:\n");
    if(!InternetQueryOption(hInternet, INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, &List, &nSize))
       printf("InternetQueryOption failed! (%d)\n", GetLastError());
       if(Option[0].Value.pszValue != NULL)
       printf("%s\n", Option[0].Value.pszValue);

    if((Option[2].Value.dwValue & PROXY_TYPE_AUTO_PROXY_URL) == PROXY_TYPE_AUTO_PROXY_URL)
      printf("PROXY_TYPE_AUTO_PROXY_URL\n");

    if((Option[2].Value.dwValue & PROXY_TYPE_AUTO_DETECT) == PROXY_TYPE_AUTO_DETECT)
       printf("PROXY_TYPE_AUTO_DETECT\n");

    INTERNET_VERSION_INFO      Version;
    nSize = sizeof(INTERNET_VERSION_INFO);

    InternetQueryOption(hInternet, INTERNET_OPTION_VERSION, &Version, &nSize);

    if(Option[0].Value.pszValue != NULL)
       GlobalFree(Option[0].Value.pszValue);

    if(Option[3].Value.pszValue != NULL)
       GlobalFree(Option[3].Value.pszValue);

    if(Option[4].Value.pszValue != NULL)
       GlobalFree(Option[4].Value.pszValue);

  }

}
```

In Windows XP, it hits memory access violation trying to access something behind `NULL` pointer.

```
    wininet.dll!PROXY_SERVER_LIST::CopyString(void) Unknown
    wininet.dll!PROXY_INFO::GetProxySettings(struct INTERNET_PROXY_INFO_EX *,int)   Unknown
    wininet.dll!PROXY_INFO_GLOBAL::GetProxySettings(struct INTERNET_PROXY_INFO_EX *,int)    Unknown
    wininet.dll!QueryPerConnOptions(void *,int,struct INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LISTA *) Unknown
    wininet.dll!_InternetQueryOptionA@16()  Unknown
>   InternetQueryOption.exe!main(int argc=1, char * * argv=0x003e2e60) Line 55  C++
    InternetQueryOption.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 278    C
```

Comment: What kind of crash - memory access violation, error code, call stack, anything?

Comment: Access violation - thanks for the feedback. I updated the question.

Comment: With access violation you should set debugger up to break on exception, and examine call stack (and paste it here). You will see chain on functions on the stack and this is relevant information. For us here it is more of a guess work. I, for instance, don't like the line `printf("%s\n", Option[0].Value.pszValue);` because it looks like you are printing a string from uninitialized location.

Comment: Thanks, but I know perfectly well how to debug an application. Actually it's no guess work for you, because you can use the code as it is. That's why i provided the sample in the first place. And as the title states quite obviously the crash happens inside `InternetQueryOption`.

Comment: Crashes for me, looks like a bug in Windows XP... which you might want to post on MS Connect, though I doubt it is going to draw any attention (esp that it is fixed on more recent versions).

Comment: Which `InternetQueryOption()`?

Comment: @Deanna: the first one, which is to take those 5 options.

Comment: Does it work if you use the `InternetQueryOptionW` Unicode variant? Don't forget to pass a `INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LISTW`

Comment: @MSalters: I tried yesterday - the same access violation.